# Как придумать и описать три оригинальных свадебных подарка в жанре шутливой пьесы?

Tags: литература

**Это сценарий небольшой праздничной пьески** (он дан в приложении). По восточному календарю наступающий 2023год посвящен Кролику, а также Зайцу и Коту.

Сценарию не хватает **трех интересных  и оригинальных подарков** — это в нем как раз самое главное. Хотелось бы, чтобы участники форума что-нибудь посоветовали в этом плане.

Итак, нужно **небольшое литературное произведение в любом жанре**, например: описание свадебного торта, роскошного наряда невесты, свадебного путешествия, признания в любви, фантастической или смешной истории и т.п.

Вопрос, скорее всего, будет конкурсный, если участники проявят активность.

**Сценарий**

1. У царя на службе были

Трое: Кролик, Заяц, Кот.

И с царевичем дружили

Те же: Кролик, Заяц, Кот.

Ох, ругали втихаря

Мамки батюшку-царя:

Слуг других получше нет?

Только это был секрет…

2. Царь все в войнах да походах,

Но сынка не забывал,

На ученье-воспитанье

Не жалел отец старанья.

3. Скоро годы проходили,

И походы утомили,

Все одно: и там, и тут, —

Потянуло на уют.

У камина посидеть

Да на внуков поглядеть.

4. Вырос сын высок и статен,

Да лицом-то как пригож,

Как на батюшку похож!

Мальчик вежливый, смышленый,

Но какой-то отстраненный.

Как  с ним трубку покурить

По душам поговорить.

5. Собралася вмиг родня,

Разобрали все причины,

И отцовские кручины.

Виноватых  что искать!

Эти трое! Их прогнать!

Срочно Ванечке жениться,

Вот тогда остепенится.

6. Вмиг красавицу сыскали.

Да еще такую кралю!

Только вот не так проста.

Посмотрела, помолчала,

Три подарка заказала,

Если хоть один сгодится

Для красавицы-девицы.

Вот тогда и свадьбе быть.

Да, пригож,  и что с того, —

Муж ей нужен с политесом

И духовным интересом.

**Пусть проявит этот франт**

**Свой писательский талант…**

7. Как невестушка, сынок?

Разберемся, будет срок…

Настежь терема ворота —

И помчалася охота!

8. А царь-батюшка вздыхает:

Так ли Ваня рифмы знает?

**Где там Кролик, Заяц, Кот?**

**Быстро вышли все вперед!**

**Кто принцессе угодит —**

**Того щедро наградит!**

9.Три подарка для девицы?

Что за дело! Нам сгодится!

Что там шепчет Ване Кот?

Нет, так дело не пойдет!

Чтоб до ранних  петухов

Был подарочек готов!